# Zoho Deluge - How to compare list entries in Deluge

Tags: json, zoho, zoho-deluge

I currently have two lists, one is from an external api (splynx), which returns a list of all customers, and another list which returns a list of all Account names from the contacts module in Zoho crm, at the moment, I just want write a code that confirms if the two lists contain matching entries (like one entry in the splynx list matches another entry in the crm list).
What I actually want to achieve is for each matching entry, I want to update crm records with the Customer ID field from Splynx, with a custom field called Splynx ID in the accounts module in CRM (because this ID is auto generated so as to maintain consistency across both apps). I want to know if this even achievable.

This is the code I have written so far

```
headersmap = Map();
headersmap.put("Authorization","Basic xxxxxxx);
response = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://selfcare.dotmac.ng/api/2.0/admin/customers/customer?"
    type :GET
    headers:headersmap
];
AccountlistSplynx = List();
li1 = List();
li2 = List();
li3 = List();
rows = response.toJSONList();
rows1 = response.toJSONList();
rows2 = response.toJSONList();
for each  row in rows
{
    Name = row.getjson("name");
    AccountlistSplynx.add(Name);
}
for each  row in rows1
{
    Address = row.getjson("street_1");
    li1.add(Address);
}
for each  row in rows2
{
    CustomerID = row.getjson("id");
    li2.add(CustomerID);
}

Accountlistzoho = List();
mp = Map();
contacts = zoho.crm.getRecords("Contacts");
for each  contact in contacts
{
    account = ifnull(contact.getJSON("Account_Name"),Map());
    if(account.size() > 0)
    {
        accountname = account.getJSON("name");
        Accountlistzoho.add(accountname);
    }
}

if ( Accountlistzoho == AccountlistSplynx ) 
{
    info "Matching records!";

}
else 
{
    info "No matching records!";
}
```

I also want to know if this is the best route to follow in trying to achieve this because I had already imported these contacts from Splynx to CRM before I realized that I did not create the custom field for Accounts

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the intersect list function:

```
<variable> = <listVariableOne>.intersect( <listVariableTwo> );
```

---

**Note!**:

```
<listVariableOne>.intersect( <listVariableTwo> );
```

and

```
<listVariableTwo>.intersect( <listVariableOne> );
```

should return the same intersection set but sometimes one of these calls returns a smaller set.    To work around this, call intersect() both ways and if they differ use the one that gives the expected set.

---

**For this task intersect() would be used something like this**:

```
headersmap = Map();
headersmap.put("Authorization","Basic xxxxxxx);
response = invokeurl
[
    url:"https://selfcare.dotmac.ng/api/2.0/admin/customers/customer?"
    type :GET
    headers:headersmap
];

// Note: Using a Map to associate Splynx names and ids.
SplynxMap = Map();
rows = response.toJSONList();
for each row in rows
{
  SplynxMap.put(row.getjson("name"), row.getjson("id");
}

// Here make a list of Splynx names based on the map keys.
AccountlistSplynx = List();
AccountlistSplynx = SplynxMap.keys();

// Intersect() function
ItemsToProcess = Accountlistzoho.intersect(AccountlistSplynx);


// Get Zoho record and update with Splynx Customer ID
// Here is one way to do this, but probably not the best or 
// most efficient.  There is should be a way in CRM to request
// a specific record based on the "name" field and avoid
// looping through contacts for each item to process.
for each item in itemsToProcess
{
  for each contact in contacts
  {
    account = ifnull(contact.getJSON("Account_Name"),Map());
    if(account.size() > 0)
    {
        if ( item ==  account.getJSON("name"))
        {
          account.Splynx_ID = SplynxMap.get(item);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you, could you please put me through the process of updating these records with their Splynx ID's?

Comment: @PromiseOkoli, I added some more detail about one way to add the Splynx IDs to Zoho records.  See it it helps get you through the process of updating these records with their Splynx ID's

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your needs, do you want to update Zoho CRM records if they are matched in Splynx records?

Step 1:
Store all Splynx records into the List data type variable in the deluge.
Store all Zoho records into the List data type variable in the deluge.

Step 2:
Assume that API field Names of both Lists are not equally matched.

Step 3:
This is how to determine matched records in Zoho records if we assume that Account Name is the criteria to be said it is matched. Please note that api_field_name or keys will be different from your actual data.

```
SplynxData = {{"s_account_name":"Account A","ID":"s_ID_1"},{"s_account_name":"Account B","ID":"s_ID_2"},{"s_account_name":"Account C","ID":"s_ID_3"},{"s_account_name":"Account D","ID":"s_ID_4"}};
ZohoData = {{"z_account_name":"Account A","ID":"z_ID_1"},{"z_account_name":"Account B"},{"z_account_name":"Account C"}};

ZohoData_group_Name = Map();
for each ZohoData_item in ZohoData{
    item_map = Map();
    ZohoData_group_Name.put(ZohoData_item.get('z_account_name'),ZohoData_item);
}
for each SplynxData_item in SplynxData{
    matched_zoho_item =  ZohoData_group_Name.get(SplynxData_item.get('s_account_name')) ;
    if (matched_zoho_item != null){
        info matched_zoho_item;
        //Do zoho.crm.updateRecords methods
        
    }
}
```

You can try this deluge script in https://deluge.zoho.com/tryout.
Please refer to this link on how to update Zoho Records https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/crm/update-record.html